# Delete trigger not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

i have create a simple delete trigger which is fired but 0 rows effected. parent table record deleted. but the table from the record also should deleted not deleted. i have the following query.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[studentAuditActionDelete] on [dbo].[tblStudent]

after delete
AS

declare @studentId_Audit int;

    select @studentId_Audit = i.studentID from inserted i;  
    delete from studentAudit
    where
    studentId_Audit = @studentId_Audit
    PRINT 'AFTER Delete trigger fired.'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried selecting from the `deleted`

```
select @studentId_Audit = d.studentID from deleted d;
```

Remember that the `deleted` can contain multiple rows and you only select one of them! (That is for all triggers to remember `inserted`, `updated`, and `deleted`)

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare variable in trigger, use simple JOIN with source table DELETED and you will be able use multiple deleting

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[studentAuditActionDelete] on [dbo].[tblStudent]
FOR DELETE
AS
  DELETE a
  FROM studentAudit a JOIN deleted d ON a.studentId_Audit = d.studentID  
  PRINT 'AFTER Delete trigger fired.'
```